# React-native iOS : Cocoapods could not find compatible version for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly","Google-Maps-iOS-Utils" & "GoogleMaps"

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, google-maps, cocoapods

I am getting the following error while running `pod install` for my react-native project.
I tried running `pod install --repo-update` and `pod repo update`, but it didn't work for me.

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
> "Firebase/CoreOnly":   In Podfile:
> RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`) was resolved to 8.4.3, which depends on
> Firebase/CoreOnly (~> 6.30.0)
>
> ```
> RNFBFirestore (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore`) was resolved to
> ```
>
> 7.8.2, which depends on
> Firebase/Firestore (~> 6.30.0) was resolved to 6.30.0, which depends on
> Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.30.0)
>
> ```
> RNFBRemoteConfig (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/remote-config`) was resolved
> ```
>
> to 6.7.1, which depends on
> Firebase/Core (~> 6.13.0) was resolved to 6.13.0, which depends on
> Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.13.0)
>
> CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
> "Google-Maps-iOS-Utils":   In Podfile:
> Google-Maps-iOS-Utils
>
> ```
> react-native-google-maps (from `../node_modules/react-native-maps`) was resolved to 0.27.1, which
> ```
>
> depends on
> Google-Maps-iOS-Utils (= 2.1.0)
>
> CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleMaps":
> In Podfile:
> react-native-google-maps (from `../node_modules/react-native-maps`) was resolved to 0.27.1, which
> depends on
> Google-Maps-iOS-Utils (= 2.1.0) was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
> GoogleMaps
>
> ```
> react-native-google-maps (from `../node_modules/react-native-maps`) was resolved to 0.27.1, which
> ```
>
> depends on
> GoogleMaps (= 3.5.0)

Can anyone give a possible solution to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

I solved it like this:

- I checked my `node_modules/react-native-maps/react-native-google-maps.podspec` and I have the following versions:

```
require 'json'

package = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'package.json')))

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
...
  s.dependency 'GoogleMaps', '5.1.0'
  s.dependency 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', '3.10.3'
...
```

- then I updated my `Podfile` like this:

```
    rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
    pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
    pod 'GoogleMaps', '5.1.0' # <<<<---- I added the '5.1.0' version here
    pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', '3.10.3' # <<<<---- I added the '3.10.3' version here
```

- I ran `pod install` and I got this error: `[!] The platform of the target` inguru`(iOS 10.0) may not be compatible with`GoogleMaps (5.1.0) `which has a minimum requirement of iOS 11.0.`
- I updated the minimum required build version to `11.0` on top of my `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

- I ran `pod install` again and everything worked.

Comment: By editing platform: ios, '11.0' to '12.0' it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Took me some time. But fixed it. Be sure the version of iOS is at least `11`. You can change it at the top of your `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you installed everything correctly and pod repo update doesn't work still, remove your Podfile.lock then do 'pod install' again.

Answer (score -1):

After some tries i delete podfile.lock and then pod install and it work

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31840716)